# Why a disk drive could not be connected (physically) to 2+ computers?

Tags: hard-drive, computer-architecture

A friend of mine if a disk drive could be connected to more than one computer and I jumped directly to the "no" answer, but I realized that pretty much any inconvenient I could think of would be easy to solve. So I am rethinking my position: if this is not possible, why?

I've been thinking that the most obvious problems would be:

- read / write conflicts (but it would be solvable by queuing operations or transactions)
- availability (but at least one power source would be enough to keep it working)
- most other problems I could think of are not at the hardware level but rather driver level upwards

Furthermore, there are very common approaches where several drives span logical drives, and network file systems deal with these issues pretty much consistently.

However, it seems that this is not a common thing -- where is my assumption wrong?

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, I am sorry but I disagree, there are systems that allow simultaneous access.  They are not particularly common, but they certainly exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could think of would be easy to solve. So I am rethinking my position: if this is not possible, why?

Because almost none of the existing filesystems are designed to support this.  The assumption of most filesystems is that a single computer has full control.

BUT

**There are filesystems and technologies that DO support multiple computers attaching to it.**  The other answers suggesting that this is simple not possible are incorrect, or at least incomplete.

One relatively common setup would be like this.  Take a standard drive, put it in a Storage enclosure that supports iSCSI, Setup two VMware ESXi hosts at the same iSCSI lun with and use the VMFS.  [VMFS is cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_VMFS) filesystem specifically designed for access by multiple systems.  But as I mentioned you need hardware specifically designed for this.  Like iSCSI, Fiber Channel, or a few other technologies.

> VMware VMFS (Virtual Machine File System) is VMware, Inc.'s cluster file system. It is used by VMware ESX Server and the company's flagship server virtualization suite, vSphere (and predecessor VMware Infrastructure).[4] It was developed and is used to store virtual machine disk images, including snapshots. **Multiple servers can read/write the same filesystem simultaneously**, while individual virtual machine files are locked.

NTFS on Windows 2012R2 also supports simultaneous access by two systems.  This is using a technology Microsoft calls [Clustered Shared Volumes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868.aspx).

Comment: +! Linking to Wikipedia's [list of shared-disk file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#SHARED) might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Its all about the interface, and how your system is architected.

In the beginning, you had a separate drive controller and a hard disk that needed a specific design to work. Then you had IDE which had the electronics for controlling the drives built into the drives.

However, the protocols your computers use to talk to drives are designed for a single host and X number of devices- SCSI and ATA for example have networked variants with similar commands, but they're still one host to many guests. You'd need a drive communication protocol that can 'politely' handle requests from more than one system, buffer things, and store them. So happens that the 'best' way to do that is to throw the complexity to a host system that handles ethernet, storage protocols and such, and to split that cost between many drives.

Your physical interfaces are *also* designed to be exposed to one host (using a point to point or bus interface) rather than many hosts (using a star or bus topology).

Its still *really* new , but something like the new [seagate kinetic drives](http://www.seagate.com/sg/en/tech-insights/kinetic-vision-how-seagate-new-developer-tools-meets-the-needs-of-cloud-storage-platforms-master-ti/) - they're drives that use a *native* ethernet interface, would count as a 'hard drive' that can be directly connected (or connected through a switch) to many drives, using a protocol designed to connect to multiple hosts. In essence you're treating each drive as its own system. Microprocessors have gotten cheap and powerful enough that running a small 'server' per drive, connecting it via ethernet/ip and sending/receiving/buffering and storing the data can be done on the drive itself.

So, you could do it, with drastically different design choices than have been made historically. There's nothing stopping you (if you happen to be a HDD manufacturer) from throwing in a small OS, a cheap arm processor, and a ethernet interface and building a utterly tiny directly network attached hard drive capable of handling many clients. You'd just need to be able/willing to throw out the DAS-centric physical, electrical and signalling protocols that have worked pretty well so far for personal systems, storages, and various SAN/NAS arrays.

Comment: It would not be “NAS-like”. It would simply be **a** NAS.

Comment: Point accepted, and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I put to you the problem is with limitations on the connection to the PC's.  SATA and SAS are electrically not designed to be connected to more then 1 system, and being that its a serial protocol, I don't belive USB is either.  (IE I put to you the problem is the lack of demand and lower level hardware/logic more then the OS layer)

This means that the logic to access the drive will physically need to be abstracted - and indeed the most logical way to do this would be to use something like a network cable and converter, which in a lot of ways (but not exactly) is what a NAS is.

(I note like @Zordache said there are filesystems which can support this - in the Linux world GFS and OCFS are common, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems lists a whole bunch of them in the "Shared-disk file systems section - so it would be possible at the OS and higher levels).

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-attached_storage) article discusses the issue at a technical level - by definition a NAS allows shared storage, DAS only single - and the common disk protocols are all DAS.

Answer (score -1):

Your assumption is correct. A single drive can only have 1 computer attached to it.

**Work Arounds**

You could turn the drive into a NAS storage, but simultaneous use could results in a problem if the network gets congested. This includes plugging the drive into a router and using Windows sharing. Note that the latter can only function if the computer is powered on and it is slower compared to the former.

Another workaround would be some sort of system which would un-mount the drive on one system and mount it on another. This would need some sort of automated script and would need a system to check if the other system is on. Also, external factors like booting may present a problem.

**Final Verdict**

My final verdict is that simultaneous use is outruled if the drive is not a NAS drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to single drive over network (it needs special fileserver, but my cheap home router can do it). Its handles file conflicts, locks and other things. Base file IO (SATA, PATA) is not handle this cases, its only read and write sectors.

Power - if you connect to different power sources, you can burn it, because of different power phases.

Comment: Power phases are not an issue, because the drive accepts DC.

Comment: Ок. I have three phases, coming in my room and two of them powers two diffrent DC soources. So, distance betwen zeroes would be near 100 V.

Comment: The zeroes are supposed to be grounded.